# How well does the "A" fit in the "B"?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

I'm trying to find two words that describe how well a single person/object/thing would fit in with some kind of situation/grouping/place/things.

A few examples:

- "How well does the *'Student'* fit in with the *'Class'*?"
- "I feel that the *'Employee'* fits in well at her new *'Job'*."
- "Do you think the *'New Chair'* fits in with the *'Rest of the room'*?"

Is there any one word or phrase that could be used to describe or stand in for each of *'Student'*, *'Employee'* and '*New Chair*' and another word or phrase that could describe or stand in for *'Class'*, *'Job'* and *'Rest of the room'* in use in the above sentances?

I.e. For:

- "How well does the *'A'* fit in with the *'B'*?"
- "I feel that the *'A'* fits in well at her new *'B'*."
- "Do you think the *'A'* fits in with the *'B'*?"

Is there a single *'A'* and *'B'* that exists to cover every use?

I was thinking something like *'Subject'* and *'Group'* ("How well does the *'Subject'* fit in with the *'Group'*?") except *'Group'* doesn't necessarily work in every case (*'Job'* isn't always used to just refer to a group of people working together) and *'Subject'* could be vague (is *'A'* or *'B'* the subject?). Is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can come up with (although it's a bit 1984 for a human subject) is:

***Specimen/Environment***